# custom fastapi query parameter validation

Tags: python, fastapi

Is there any way to have custom validation logic in a FastAPI query parameter?

**example**

I have a [`FastAPI`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) app with a bunch of request handlers taking `Path` components as query parameters. For example:

```py
def _raise_if_non_relative_path(path: Path):
    if path.is_absolute():
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=409,
            detail=f"Absolute paths are not allowed, {path} is absolute."
        )

@app.get("/new",)
def new_file(where: Path):
    _raise_if_non_relative_path(where)
    # do save a file
    return Response(status_code=requests.codes.ok)

@app.get("/new",)
def delete_file(where: Path):
    _raise_if_non_relative_path(where)
    # do save a file
    return Response(status_code=requests.codes.ok)
```

I was wondering if there is way to ensure that the handler is not even called when the given file path is absolute.
Now I have to repeat myself with `_raise_if_non_relative_path` everywhere.

**what I tried**

- `fastapi.Query`: 
  This only allows very basic validation (string length and regex).
  I could define a *absolute path regex* in this example.
  But a regex solution is really not generic, I want to validate with a custom function.
- Subclass `pathlib.Path` with validation logic in `__init__`: 
  This doesn't work, the type given in the type signature is ignored,
  and the object in my handler is a regular `pathlib.PosixPath`.
- Use `@app.middleware`: 
  this can work but seems overkill
  since not all my request handlers deal with `Path` objects.
- `class RelativePath(pydantic.Basemodel)`: 
  I.e. define a class with single `path` field, which I can validate however I want.
  Unfortunately, this does not work for query parameters.
  If I do this, the request handler insists on having a json content body.
  Or at least that is what the swagger docs say.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the kind of validation that [the `Depends` dependency management function](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/) is well-suited for. It allows you to define dependencies for given view functions, and add logic to validate (and lazily create) those dependencies. This gives a set of composable dependencies that can be re-used in those views where they are required.

You can create a `relative_where_query` dependency, and then depend on that to perform any required validation:

```py
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, Response, Query
from fastapi.exceptions import HTTPException
from pathlib import Path
import requests

app = FastAPI()

def relative_where_query(where: Path = Query(...)):
    if where.is_absolute():
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=409,
            detail=f"Absolute paths are not allowed, {where} is absolute."
        )
        
    return where
    
@app.get("/new")
def new_file(where: Path = Depends(relative_where_query)):
    return Response(status_code=requests.codes.ok)
```

This gives small, easily readable (and understandable) view functions, while the dependency ("I need a relative path from the `where` query parameter") has been moved to its own definition.

You can then re-use this dependency in every view function that require a relative path from the `where` query parameter (and you can further decompose and recompose these dependencies further if necessary).

**Update 2023-05-01**: If you want to generalize this handling to decouple the field name from the validation function, you can do that by generating a dynamic dependency. This examples creates a dynamic base model with Pydantic to do it - but there's surely other ways.

Since we now raise the error inside a Pydantic validator, we add an exception handler to give a proper error response if the path isn't valid.

The magic itself happens inside `path_validator` - this function takes the name given to it, [uses it as a field name in a `create_model` call - which dynamically creates a Pydantic model from its parameters](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/models/#dynamic-model-creation). This model is then used as a dependency in the controller.

The name given as an argument to the function will be the actual parameter name - both when being called (i.e. in the URL in this case) and when the documentation is displayed. The `path` name in the controller function itself is only relevant inside the function, and isn't used in the documentation or as the query parameter (the field name in the model is used for that).

```py
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, Response, Query, Request
from fastapi.exceptions import HTTPException
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from pathlib import Path
from pydantic import create_model, validator
import requests

app = FastAPI()


class PathNotAbsoluteError(Exception):
    pass


@app.exception_handler(PathNotAbsoluteError)
async def value_error_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: PathNotAbsoluteError):
    return JSONResponse(
        status_code=400,
        content={"message": str(exc)},
    )
    

def path_is_absolute(cls, value):
    if not value.is_absolute():
        raise PathNotAbsoluteError("Given path is not absolute")
    
    return value


def path_validator(param_name):
    validators = {
        'pathname_validator': validator(param_name)(path_is_absolute)
    }
        
    return create_model(
        "AbsolutePathQuery", 
        **{param_name: (Path, Query(...))},
        __validators__=validators,
    )


@app.get("/path")
def new_file(path: Path = Depends(path_validator("where"))):
    return Response(status_code=requests.codes.ok)
```

You can now reuse this in any location you want by adding a dependency on a given parameter name:

```py
def new_file(path: Path = Depends(path_validator("my_path"))):
    ...

def old_file(path: Path = Depends(path_validator("where"))):
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. I knew about dependencies but somehow I was locked in the mindset that they were meant for accessing external resources like databases and such.

Comment: After a while it clicks and you see how much you actually can describe as "this function depends on .." and get very compact view functions. It's a powerful feature.

Comment: It's a real shame that this solution requires all parameters using `relative_where_query` to be called `where`. No other name is possible. There doesn't seem to be a way to apply `Depends` validators to routes which have differently-named query params.

Comment: Sure there is - you can use `create_model` from Pydantic to create a dynamic dependency. I'll add an example.

Comment: Instead of using the "422 Unprocessable Entity" responses, this now returns some specific error for this validation failure, which is undesirable.

Comment: @JanneEnberg OPs question used 409 as the response code explicitly, which is why this example is based on using that. Thank you for your answer showing how to return the common 422 error.

Answer (score 2):

**Note: There is atm still a chance you may be using an older version of Pydantic and there is some chance it will require a modified solution. This is for projects using Pydantic >= 2.0.**

FastAPI uses Pydantic under the hood also for validating parameters not defined as a Pydantic model, and it passes along the extra arguments to `Path()`, `Query()` and `Body()` to the `FieldInfo` object in Pydantic.

This means you can pass an extra `annotation=` argument to `Query()` and `Path()`, which can then be used to define a custom validator with `AfterValidator()`.

```py
from typing import Annotated
from fastapi import APIRouter, Path, Query

router = APIRouter("/prefix")


# Define validator according to Pydantic patterns
# https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/validators/
def lowercase_validator(value: str) -> str:
    assert value.lower() == value, f"{value} is not lowercase"
    return value


# Define route using Path and Query parameters
# https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/path-params-numeric-validations/
# https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/
@router.get("/{path}")
async def some_path(
        path: str = Path(annotation=Annotated[str, AfterValidator(lowercase_validator)]),
        arg: str = Query(annotation=Annotated[str, AfterValidator(lowercase_validator)]),
):
    pass
```

This solution leads to FastAPI directly handling this as a part of the normal validation and returning the same type of `422 Unprocessable Entity` error as all other validation failures.

In the case of the original question then you would make a validator something like

```py
import pathlib
def validate_relative_path(path: pathlib.Path):
    assert not path.is_absolute(), f"{path} is not relative"
    return Path
```

And use it in the route something like

```py
@app.get("/new",)
def new_file(where: pathlib.Path = Query(annotation=Annotated[str, AfterValidator(validate_relative_path)])):
    pass
```